# User coming from an external link is redirected to another page if he tries to go back to the previous page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to make the user coming from an external link view one more page before going back out of the site, the idea is for him to be redirected to another page of my site if he tries to return to the page

```
I need it to work only if the previous page is an external link so as not to disturb the user's navigation
```